# Want to change store language drop down to store language flags?

Tags: magento-1.7, template, language

I am getting store languages in drop down format, while i want to show flags instead of store language drop down..

The child element i am using to call is :

```
$this->getChildHtml('store_language');
```

What do i have to need in the code so i can get the flags instead of drop down...

I am new in magento, so have not much idea..

please help me..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in one of your layout files inside the `<layout>` tag.  Preferably the `local.xml` located in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout`. (If there isn't one, create it).

```
<default>
    <reference name="store_language">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/switch/flags.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```